# String encoding issue in Spark SQL/DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have this csv file which has two columns: id (int), name(string). When I read the file into pyspark throught the following code:

```
schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("name", StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.read.csv("file.csv", 
                             header=False, schema = schema)
```

On executing `df.first()` I get the following output:

```
Row(artistid=1240105, artistname=u'Andr\xe9 Visior')
```

This is the original row from the file:

```
1240105,André Visior
```

How do I go about displaying the name as it is?

Answer (score 0):

save the csv file by opening as CSV(utf-8)

Comment: How do I open it as a UTF8 file in pyspark?

Comment: no open file in eexcel and save it back as CSV(utf-8) and then apply the same program.

Answer (score -1):

Not a very clean way, but here is a quick fix.

```
s = "1240105,André Visior"
s.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8").replace("\xc3\xa9 ","e'")

>>
"1240105,Andre'Visior"
```

You may want to look to `Latin-1` to `Unicode` / `ASCII` conversion [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I want all the strings in the name column to be as they are in the file, not just the first row